# .htaccess: Trigger PHP script when image opened and pass GET parameter

Tags: php, image, .htaccess

I have an image that is stored on my web server and accessible like this: https://www.example.com/images/MyImage.jpg?id=555

It there a way, e.g. with `.htaccess`, to toggle a script https://www.example.com/images/script.php as soon as the image is opened and pass the value of `id` to it?

I don't want to embed the image into an PHP script like this: https://www.example.com/images/MyImage.php?id=555

Comment: You can rewrite the _request_ for that image to a script - but then you will have to take care of sending the actual image data to the client from within that script yourself.

Comment: @04FS I know, but this isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: You can use a file observer like [inotify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.inotify.php).

Comment: your question is unclear. Also `I don't want to embed the image into an PHP script like this` - why would you do that anyway?

Comment: Then the answer is No - you can not use .htaccess to “trigger” additional scripts, or to cause any additional requests in parallel to the one you are actually currently handling.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. In your `.htaccess` you redirect your image URL to a PHP file. In this php file you execute your `script.php`, and after executing it, you include the image and set the correct return type headers, so your image is treated like an image.

Your `.htaccess` might look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !script\.php
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ script.php?img=images/$1 [L, QSA]
```

Comment: If you read the comments below the question, you’d realize this is not what they are looking for.

Comment: Why would that be? The question mentions that the URL shouldn't look like a PHP file ('myImage.php'), but this method keeps the filename intact, and returns the resource as an image, while also executing a script. I think this is exactly what the question asks for.

Comment: _“but then you will have to take care of sending the actual image data to the client from within that script yourself”_ - _“I know, but this isn't what I'm looking for”_